# How do you know if you are under a trial or if you are just suffering?

Tags: suffering, spiritual-growth

Hypothetically, if you are going through a painful situation:

- Is it because God is trying to grow you/redirect you?
- Or is it a result of sinful actions?

Comment: Hi Nilesh and welcome to our Q&A site!  The question is interesting, but it verges a bit close to [asking for pastoral advice](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/255/914 "We try to avoid those questions!") in my opinion.  There are lot's of individual details that make it difficult to provide a general answer.  It _might_ help if you specified [which Christian tradition](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379/914 "We are trying to be more descriptive than prescriptive.") you are interested in finding out about.

Comment: @NileshTailor: there is no one answer to that and no one alive can ever know that.

Comment: And what about those who are born with a painful congenital condition?

Comment: There are more than just the two possibilities you mention. God might be protecting you from a particular temptation (too sick to commit adultery?), or giving others an opportunity to practice kindness toward you, or warning others of what might happen to them, or setting the stage for a miraculous cure.  There are probably more options that I'm not thinking of right now. And God is so smart that he might arrange for a single instance of suffering to serve several purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his book, *Secrets of the Vine* (based on John 15), Bruce Wilkinson addresses this very question.

In both situations, there is pain, so the presence of pain does not necessarily mean one is under God's discipline, although it could.

The key thing is to examine one's life to see if there is any unconfessed sin and to ask God  to reveal that.  One could also discuss it with a close friend or pastor to see if there is anything that other people have noticed.  If one is honest and there is nothing that God reveals, then it may be that the issue is purely one of growth.

Bruce Wilkinson distinguishes between the two by indicating that whenever there is pain because of sin, the pain continues until the person stops sinning.  However, if it is purely a matter of growth, the pain will continue until God has finished His work.

Comment: Hmm, I need to read that book again. Its actually one of my favorite books but I guess I missed that part.

Comment: @Narnian, Are there any biblical support for the claim "the pain continues until the person stops sinning"?